# how to apply sas SQL substr function to all column, variables in a single line to do the exact same substr to every variable

Tags: sql, sorting, sas, substr

A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, ... (these are the column names or variables)

I want to use the the substr function to select all of them based on the associated number.

Something like; input substr(variable.2)

I'm pretty sure it can be done, but I'm not sure how. Any idea?

I want to be able to select the number after the letter.

I want to order them as 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
Because every week I get more column and A1 become A2 and the new week become A1 and then A5 become A6.

So I want to reverse their order. I thought of doing:
order by input substr(variable.2)    But I don't know how to make it work.

Best,
H.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary tables, `proc sql`, and the `:into` statement to build your SQL select statement. For this example, we're assuming your dataset name is called `HAVE`. We're going to select all variables from `dictionary.columns` that start with A in `HAVE` to build a SQL statement:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select name
    into :vars separated by ', '
    from dictionary.columns
    where     memname = 'HAVE'
          AND name LIKE 'AA_%A_BB'
    order by input(compress(name,,'KD'), 8.) desc
    ;
quit;
```

This creates the macro variable `&vars`, which looks like this:

`AA_A5_BB, AA_A4_BB, AA_A3_BB, AA_A2_BB, AA_A1_BB`

You can pass that right into a SQL select statement:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select &vars
        from have
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: nliteral may be a useful function here :)

Comment: How would I use nliteral to reorder my functions?

Comment: Also, Stu Sztukowski, I need to keep the letter in the name. also, how would that function change if the name was something like ; aa_a1_bb? Would it simply be name LIKE 'aa_a%_bb' and then order by substr(name, 5) ? Because the % is in 5th position?

Comment: @Reeza that is awesome! I wish I knew about this function years ago! hugo the solution changes slightly. I've updated the code to fit what you have described here. If this does not work then please post sample data of what you are reading in and your desired output in a tabular format.